# Exclude Arrays from Object Literal types in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, object-literal

Consider the TS snippet:

```
type bar = { [key: string] : any } 
const foo: bar = [];  // Works, No type errors; Arrays are accepted !
```

**I want to keep Arrays out and only pure objects to be accepted!**

Now I know that in JS arrays are objects. And that is why the above statements work perfectly fine in Typescript and doesn't give out any Type Collisions.

I tried using `object, {}, Record<string, any>` in `bar` above and all seem to accept arrays.

One possible solution I found by trial and error is :

```
type bar = Record<string, unknown>;  // or any other type other than `any`
const foo: bar = [];  // Now arrays are not accepted !!
```

Now I want to know if this is the correct/best way (seemed like a hack to me) to keep Arrays out of Object Literal Notation Types or is there any better way?

Comment: do you know the structure (i.e. the keys) of your object?

Comment: It is supposed to be a initialization for a store For Ex. `{}` or `[]` but only one of those and not both at a time.

Comment: @VikramK have you found a better option so far?

Comment: Not yet! @Zheka

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `any` is that using it basically bypasses type checks. Which leads to weird results, such as allowing an array to pass as an object type.

Ideally you should be able to provide some known keys and value types to the type definition. For example:

```
type bar = {
  baz: string;
  [key: string]: any;
};

// this produces a type error: 
// Property 'baz' is missing in type 'never[]' but required in type 'bar'.
const foo: bar = [];
```

However, if you truly don't know the structure of the object, you can use `Record<string, unknown>` or `{ [key: string] : unknown }`.

Comment: This is insightful but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @VikramK how does it not answer the question? i listed two option for defining the type that accepts objects but not arrays. depending on whether you know (some of) the structure of your object, you can use one or the other.

Comment: To be more universal, you can use `PropertyKey`: `Record<PropertyKey, unknown>`. This indeed works for me.

Comment: @szaman I was looking for a better way to categorically keep Arrays out. I know the structure of my object and wasn't getting blocked for that. The question out of curiosity was looking for a better way. Types `Record<string, unknown>` and `{ [key: string] : unknown }` is known to me already, I've put in the question already. Same is the title of the question.

Comment: well, then i think you're misreading my answer. if you know the structure of the object, then you can provide known parameters to the type, like `baz` in the example above. as you can see, this produces an error if you try to assign an array.